# Showing an error in magento 2 called Email id Required on Checkout Page Razorpay payment gateway

Tags: magento2

When i try to checkout in magento 2 Using Razorpay Payment gateway showing an error Email id is required.
I have attached the snap for your reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Pb6.png

Comment: Why not raise a ticket here? https://razorpay.com/support/

Comment: thanks for you reply, I have reached them but they mentioned as the issue is form your end.